# Add Root Certificate into Android OS

Tags: android, ssl, pki

Can anyone give me a hint if it is possible to ask `Android` to include (or 'trust') additional `Root CA` in their OS ( which will be updated during next update and pre installed on the new instances)?

At this moment each website which use `SSL` certificate for `https` which is signed by our `Certificate Authority` is asking for `trusting` this website by showing

`untrusted connection warning`

Of course installing certificate manually solve the problem, but this is not the case considering number of operation which user has to make in order to use the website without concerns that he is being attacked by some kind of `men in the middle` attack.

For the record we have pass audits made by the independent organizations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. You should review Chromium's [Root Certificate Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy), and then follow up on the appropriate vendor's forum.

Answer (score 1):

[Root Certificate Policy - The Chromium Projects](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) says:

> If you are a root CA, the following contacts should be used:
>
> ...
>
> Android: Please file a bug at
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry . Note that, similar to
> Linux, the certificates included within the Android sources may be
> further altered by device manufacturers or carriers, pursuant to their
> local programs.